# how to convert a14 digit alpha numeric VDI number to an unique 8 digit string or integer

Tags: vb.net

I have an application which sends machine id as session id to webservice and all these days we had machine number as 6 digits and now we have few VDI machines which is 14 digits. The webservice allows only 6 to 8 character session id's.

Now, my question is there a way to generate 8 unique character out of 14 digit VDI machine numbers? 
I tried GetHashCode() function. It returns an integer. Convert it into a hex and then to an 8 characters long string.

dim hashCode as string = String.Format("{0:X}", sourceString.GetHashCode())

is there any better way or ideas to implement this than hashcode function?

Comment: If your VDI machine id uses a full domain of 14 'digits', that's 10^14 unique values. So then if the session id has a full domain of 8 'digits', that's 10^8 unique values.  You can't fit 10^14 values into a 10^8 sized "variable".  Hashing does not guarantee uniqueness under any circumstances,  and with those two range values, I'd expect a significant chance of collisions. If my assumptions of what kind of ids (that is, numbers/integers) you're using is incorrect, you'll need to fully explain what your two ids actually consist of.

Comment: @mark, the main problem is sometime VDI's first 4 digits and last 4 digits can be same. this is an example of VDI names ABCXY1SOEGP007  and ABCXY2SOEGP007 . if this is not the situation, I would have implemented a logic to take first and last four digit of VDI machine number.

Comment: So your unique VDI id is 14 alphanumeric? And the session is 8 numeric? That's even worse - Assuming caps only, and no reduction of similar characters that's 36 characters (A-Z, 0-9), so you've got 36^14 (more than 10^21) possible values you want to stuff into a 10^8 'variable'? You need to rethink how you're creating and tracking the session id values, given your descriptions here, the machine id probably isn't a satisfactory solution.